# Does Blood Star affect followers?

Tags: diablo-iii

My Templar follower constantly gets hit with Blood Star

[image: blood star]

Since "Templar" isn't listed on the tooltip, does this have any effect on followers at all? I notice he has the "orbs" animation above his head indicating he has the blood star affliction, but is this actually doing anything. Can I have him as my blood star meat shield?

Answer (score 4):

Followers do get the Blood Star debuff but it has no effect on them as they are not classified as one of the classes effected by the debuff.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that the followers get armour values (or at least ones that would be affected by this debuff), since they don't wear armour. And anyway the templar usually has so much health that he can take the initial hit and the ones during the debuff.

Comment: There's an armor stat for followers; why *wouldn't* they get the debuff?

Comment: @fbueckert Diablo 3 so far seems to do exactly what it says on the tooltip in most instances, I would suspect that since none of the follower 'classes' are listed that they take no damage. In addition, their abilities have no 'casting cost', so there would be no way to reliably apply this to all three follower classes (as Scoundrel and Enchantress would definitely take no damage due to having no casting cost).